# Swift switch statement force to write block of code

Tags: swift

I have question, i have enum with 3 state. On 2 of 3 that state i want to do something, but for 3rd i do not. However, when i do not put block of code below case, compiler highligh it with red and won't allow me to run app. Example:

```
func leftBarButtonTappedWithType(type: CustomNavBarViewModel.LeftBarButtonType) {

        switch type {
        case .none:
            print("")

        case .back:
            self.popViewController(animated: true)

        case .hamburger:
            self.func()

        }
    }
```

You can see that for case .none i wrote print("") because in other case i won't be able to compile. How to avoid that? Kind of ugly.

Comment: What about `case .none: break` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get your function to return in that case:

```
case .hamburger:
    return
```

Hope that helps.

Per the discussion and @MartinR 's comment, break is probably a better general solution to exit the switch statement.

Comment: break is better i think but thx.

Comment: Yes it is- can be used more generally.